# Defining Functions of a Singly Linked List

Tags: python, data-structures

Here is the code I'm working with here. I seem to be running into problems understanding and completing some of these functions. Any explanation or guidance would be appreciated to steer me in the right direction.

```
def first(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            raise EmptyError('The SLinkedList is empty')
        return self._head._element 
    
    def deleteFirst(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            raise EmptyError('The SLinkedList is empty')
        answer = self._head._element
        self._head = self._head._next
        self._size -= 1
        if self.isEmpty():  # special case when list is empty
            self._tail = None  # removed head had been the tail
        return answer
    
    def addFirst(self, e): 
        self._head = self._Node(e, self._head)  # create and link a new node
        if self._tail == None:  # special case when list was empty
            self._tail = self._head  # added head is the tail
        self._size += 1
    
    def addLast(self, e):
        newest = self._Node(e, None)  # node will be new tail node
        if self.isEmpty():
            self._head = newest  # special case: previously empty
        else:
            self._tail._next = newest
        self._tail = newest  # update reference to tail node
        self._size += 1
        
    def last(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            raise EmptyError
        else:
            return self._tail._element
        
    def _nodeAtIndex(self, index):
        temp = self._head
        cnt = 0
        
        while (temp):
            if(cnt == index):
                return temp.data
            cnt += 1
            cnt = cnt._next
        else:
            raise IndexError
        
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        aNode = self._nodeAtIndex(index)
        return aNode._element
    
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        aNode = self._nodeAtIndex(index)
        
        
    def deleteLast(self):  
        
        if self.isEmpty():
            raise EmptyError
        else:
            self._tail = 0
```

I cant figure out where to start with some of these later functions as my knowledge of the singly linked lists is still very elementary.

Comment: This looks like a homework. We will be giving you hints to solve the problem :)

Comment: Yes im not asking for the solution written out, just hints as to where to move forward

Comment: I'm sorry, but StackOverflow is for *specific* questions. Asking for general advice and "where to start" on something like this is too broad.

Comment: Which functions are you having trouble with? How do you know that you are having trouble with them - were you unable to finish writing the code? Did you try the code and run into a problem? What was the problem?

Comment: I was just unable to finish writing the code if im being honest. These data structures are making my brain very confused.

Comment: More specifically the deleteLast function getitem, setitem and nodeatIndex is giving me errors when I run

Comment: Just offering some general advice, for your delete last function you need to traverse your list till you find a node where the next value is your tail and change that next value to `None`. For setitem you need to create a function for your Node class that allows you to change its value, and for nodeatindex you need to traverse your linked list starting from the head till you reach the needed index (remember to check and see if it a 0 index start or a 1 index start)